# Does dash work in Google Cloud Datalab?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-cloud-datalab

Is it possible to run dash apps within Google Cloud Datalab?

It says it's running on specific port, but everytime I try to open it, the connection gets refused. It works fine when I try to run it in Jupyter notebook.

What could be the source of the problem?